# Using filter in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a data frame than contains more than one study. I want to filter STUDY number 7, 9, 120. I am using `filter` in the `dplyr` package like this:

```
df <- filter(data, STUDY==7, STUDY==9, STUDY==100)
```

This gives me a ZERO observations data frame. When I filter only one STUDY, it works. What is the right way to write it in order to filter a combination of studies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter(STUDY %in% c(7,9, 100))
```

Or

```
data %>%
     filter(STUDY==7|STUDY==9|STUDY==100)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(STUDY=sample(c(0,5,7,9,100,150,200),
                          25, replace=TRUE), Val=rnorm(25))
```

Comment: The first option is the way to go, I'd say.

Comment: @beginneR yes, I would also use that when there are multiple elements.